# selenium webdriver not writing data into excel sheet using apache poi

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to read and write data from excel using java selenium webdriver apache poi. But my code is reading data from excel sheet but not write data into excel sheet. I have included all jar files from poi-4.0.1 here is my code

```
try {

          // Specify the file path which you want to create or write

          File src=new File("E:\\Dharshan\\test.xlsx");

          // Load the file

          FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);

           // load the workbook

           XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

          // get the sheet which you want to modify or create

           XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);

         // getRow specify which row we want to read and getCell which column

         System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

         System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

         System.out.println(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

         System.out.println(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

         System.out.println(sh1.getRow(2).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

         System.out.println(sh1.getRow(2).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

        // here createCell will create column

        // and setCellvalue will set the value

         sh1.getRow(0).createCell(3).setCellValue("2.41.0");

         sh1.getRow(1).createCell(3).setCellValue("2.5");

         sh1.getRow(2).createCell(3).setCellValue("2.39");


        // here we need to specify where you want to save file

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(src);

         wb.write(fout);
         fout.close();

          } catch (Exception e) {

           System.out.println(e.getMessage());

          }
}
```

}

Comment: What did you see in the console?Is there any line showing null?

Comment: Ya in console it's showing null

Comment: Your code should be throwing NullPointerException when no data in excel, hence the workbook is not saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to read data from empty excel sheet once i have updated excel sheet with data now it is writing into excel sheet